# How to eliminate array item in array 3 dimension java

Tags: java, arrays, divide-and-conquer

I had a problem to eliminate candidates in a cell sudoku, I have tried to search for candidates to fill the empty cells like below

```
for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            if(game.getNumber(x, y) == 0){
                for(int z = 1; z <=9; z++){
                    if (CekRow(game, y, z) && CekColumn(game, x, z) && CekRegion(game, x, y, z)){
                        list[y][x][z-1] = z;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

then after find empty cell and fill with the candidate, i want to eliminate possible item array like method this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdy6k.png). i have someone can provide the solution to eliminate array list[y][x][z].

Comment: With eliminate do you mean make the size of the array shorter?

Comment: what are `CekRow(game, y, z)` ...etc.? and what do you mean eliminate?

Comment: `CekRow` probably checks if value `z` is present (or is possible) in row `y`.

Comment: I think it may be more productive to start with values that are already set and eliminate possibilities from the affected row, column, and region, rather than starting with unset values and trying to fill them in.

Comment: i mean the row 1 have possible like this                                                  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 0 0 5 6 0 0 9 |
0 0 3 4 5 0 0 0 9 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 0 4 0 6 0 0 9 |
0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 9 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 9                                                                                                           cause in cell on column 7 and 9 have possible item (5 and 9) , i want eliminate item (5 and 9) on array possible other etc (5,6,9) -> (0,6,0)

Comment: Your notation is a little confusing. It appears that `000050009` means that only 5 and 9 are possible, but being consistent with that notation, values like 000000000 don't make sense because they mean that no value is possible at that location.

Comment: I'd advise you to use the `BitSet` class to keep track of the possibilities for each square.

Comment: sorry to make you confused, if that possible 000000000 on cell that mean the cell already fill with number so that no possible to cell. my idea is if the cell in row 1 column 7 and the cell in row 1 column 9 have same possible 000050009. we know that we can't place 5 and 9 on cell in the same row then i want eliminate 5 and 9 on possible candidate row 1 column 3 (000056009) -> to (000006000) @DavidChoweller. thanks for your advise

Comment: If you represented each cell as a BitSet, you would be able to do this pretty easily.  Suppose you wanted to eliminate 5 and 9 on all squares in a particular row.  Then just use a `for` loop to go though every bitSet in that row and call `bitSet.clear(5)` and `bitSet.clear(9)`.  `bitSet.get(5)` returns a boolean that tells whether the 5th value is set or not.

Comment: Another option is to apply a mask with the elements you want to remove from the array using a double for loop. I edited again my answer with this new concept.

Comment: ok, thank you for your advise. i will learn how it works BitSet class in java.

Comment: @VictorChandra I have added an answer which might give you an idea of how a bit set could work to simplify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another possible data structure for a Sudoku board using the Java `BitSet` class. Each cell on the board has its possibilities tracked by a `BitSet` variable called `possibilities`.

Also shown is an example `eliminateInRow` method which eliminates numbers as possibilities from a row.  The method includes a list of columns to skip in the row, to exempt the cells that originally caused us to do the elimination (for example the cells 7 and 9 mentioned by the OP in comments on the original question).  There's also another case where if you find 3 cells all containing the possibilities (3,5,9) (for example), then you can eliminate 3,5,9 as possibilities from all other cells in the row (exempting the original 3 cells).  This method will deal with both the 2-case and the 3-case, as it uses a `List` of integers denoting columns to skip.

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.List;

class SudokuCell {
    BitSet possibilities;
    CellValue value;

    SudokuCell() {

        // Initially the value of this cell is undefined
        value = CellValue.Undefined;

        possibilities = new BitSet(9);
        // Initially every value is possible
        possibilities.set(0, 9);
    }

    // clears the possibility of 'number' from this cell
    void clear(int number) {
        possibilities.clear(number - 1);
        // If there is only one possibility left
        if (possibilities.cardinality() == 1) {

            // Set value of the cell to that possibility
            int intValue = possibilities.nextSetBit(0);
            value = CellValue.fromInteger(intValue);
        }
    }

    // returns the value of this square if it is defined
    int getValue() throws Exception {
        if (value == CellValue.Undefined) {
            throw new Exception("Undefined cell value");
        }
        return CellValue.toInteger(value);
    }

    // returns whether 'num' is still possible in this cell
    boolean isPossible(int num) {
        return possibilities.get(num-1);
    }
}

public class SudokuBoard {
    SudokuCell[][] sudokuBoard;

    // constructor
    SudokuBoard() {
        sudokuBoard = new SudokuCell[9][9];
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                sudokuBoard[row][col] = new SudokuCell();
            }
        }

    }

    // eliminate the possibility of 'num' from row 'row'
    // skipping columns in List skipCols
    void eliminateInRow(int row, int num, List<Integer> skipCols) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            if (!skipCols.contains(col)) {
                sudokuBoard[row][col].clear(num);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Below is the code for the `enum` `CellValue`, which is optional:

```
enum CellValue {
    Undefined, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine;
    public static CellValue fromInteger(int x) {
        switch (x) {
        case 0:
            return Undefined;
        case 1:
            return One;
        case 2:
            return Two;
        case 3:
            return Three;
        case 4:
            return Four;
        case 5:
            return Five;
        case 6:
            return Six;
        case 7:
            return Seven;
        case 8:
            return Eight;
        case 9:
            return Nine;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static int toInteger(CellValue value) throws Exception {
        switch (value) {
        case Undefined:
            throw new Exception("Undefined cell value");
        case One:
            return 1;
        case Two:
            return 2;
        case Three:
            return 3;
        case Four:
            return 4;
        case Five:
            return 5;
        case Six:
            return 6;
        case Seven:
            return 7;
        case Eight:
            return 8;
        case Nine:
            return 9;
        }
        throw new Exception("Undefined Cell Value");
    }
}
```